# Can I select checkboxes by ID?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I would like to select checkboxes 
not by Design name but by parameters. More specifically, I would like to 
check the checkboxes which has the parameters which are also in the data 
retrieved from the database.

Example code :

```
(checkBox) C1.checked = true;
```

This is how I can set checked right now,

but I want to do something like...

```
string[] datas = db.getData();
foreach (string data in datas) 
{
    if (data.Equals("C1")) 
    {
        C1.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Of course I can do this for every checkboxes,
but there are over 50 checkboxes and I think it's stupid 
to manually checking this but I couldn't find a way to select a particular checkbox based on the name.

Also, it would be really helpful if someone knows a way to group the textboxes,
so that I don't have to loop over every checkboxes every time. By that, I mean something like contains method within a group of checkboxes to find particular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do like below Using FindControl :

```
string[] datas = db.getData();
foreach (string data in datas) 
{
    CheckBox chk = this.Controls.Find(data, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
   if(chk !=null)
       chk.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: It works beautifully. Thank you so much.Your one minute saved my hours, if not days.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your main goal is to find:

> a way to group the textboxes, so that I don't have to loop over every
>   checkboxes every time.

You can create a Dictionary of string/Checkbox and select the checkbox that way.

Something ***like***:

```
string key = "C1";
Dictionary<string, CheckBox> pairs = new Dictionary<string, CheckBox>();
pairs[key].Checked = true;
```